# ArchLinux LibreOfficeFresh unable to start

Tags: gtk, libreoffice, archlinux, gdk

My System:

```
- ArchLinux
- LibreOfficeFresh 5.0.2-3
- Xorg116
- Catalyst Graphics Drivers
```

Problem:

```
LibreOfficeFresh is unable to start since I have installed catalyst, so since i switched
from MESA to catalyst.
```

Error Description:

```
[tekkkz@thinkpad ~]$ libreoffice 

(soffice:1022): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_set_boxed: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_BOXED (value)' failed

(soffice:1022): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gtype.c:4268: type id '0' is invalid

(soffice:1022): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: can't peek value table for type '<invalid>' which is not currently referenced
Application Error
```

Someone an idea how I can get my LibreOffice working again?

Thanks for help,
Tekkkz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the message that I saw when upgrading today

```
(18/24) upgrading libreoffice-fresh                     [##############################] 100%
> LibreOffice now uses highly experimental gtk3 vcl by default
> on some desktops. To use stable gtk2 vcl uncomment
> it in /etc/profile.d/libreoffice-fresh.{sh,csh}
```

So you can try that, uncomment the line `export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk`
 and re-login, if you don't want to logout, you have to export the variable manually in a terminal and run libreoffice from that terminal inmediately after exporting the variable.

```
export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk
soffice
```

I do that, and it works right now

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with GTK themes (and a recent change between GTK2/3). Try changing themes and see if it starts working again (it did for me).